# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'check_password'

Tags: python, django-views

I am getting Attribute error in my login view. It is saying that 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'check_password'.

This is my **view.py**:

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        u = User.objects.get(username=username)
        if username and password:
            user = authenticate(username= username, password= password)
            if not user.check_password(password):
                return render(request, 'post/login.html', {'error_message': 'Incorrect password'})
            if not user:
                return render(request, 'post/login.html', {'error_message': 'This user does not exist'})
            if not user.is_active:
                return render(request, 'post/login.html', {'error_message': 'Your account has been disabled'})
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return render(request, 'post/home.html', {'u' : u})

    return render(request, 'post/login.html')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: authenticate(username= username, password= password) returns None

Comment: If `authenticate(username=username, password=password)` returns a user, it means that the password has already been checked and valid so you don't have to call `check_password`.

Comment: I think it worked.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because your variable is empty. Make sure that you posted correcly your auth variables (username and password).

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

# I think this word properly,but you need define username field is unique for each created user


def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        if username and password:
            try:
                user = User.objects.filter(username__iexact=username)
                if user.exists() and user.first().check_password(password):
                    if user.is_active:
                        login(request, user)
                        return render(request, "post/home.html", {"user": user})
                elif user.first().is_active is False:
                    return render(
                        request,
                        "post/login.html",
                        {"error_message": "Your account has been disabled"},
                    )
                else:
                    return render(
                        request,
                        "post/login.html",
                        {"error_message": "Incorrect password"},
                    )
            except user.DoesNotExist:
                return render(
                    request,
                    "post/login.html",
                    {"error_message": "This user does not exist"},
                )
    return render(request, "post/login.html")
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76233104/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).